# ¿El evento KeyDown puede funcionar en segundo plano?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una aplicación WPF y quiero activar un método al momento de presionar una tecla específica sin necesidad de que el formulario se encuentre en primer plano, ¿Que posibilidad tiene esa solución?  Saludos!

```
    private void playSimpleSound(string url)
    {
        try {
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(url);
            simpleSound.Play(); }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Error #2"); }
    }

    private void musicKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.D1)
        {
            playSimpleSound(ruta1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Para lograr lo que planteas deberias aplicar el concepto de `Hooking`

Basicamente deberas usar las api de windows para interceptar las acciones de teclado

[A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

[Keyboard Hooking With C# – Redux](http://refactorsaurusrex.com/keyboard-hooking-with-c-redux/)

Como veras se usa la api

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx
    (int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
```

Pero podria ser mas simple si usas estas libreria

[KeyboardMouseHooks C# Library](http://keyboardmousehooks.codeplex.com/)

[EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/)